# Angular loop within a loop - table from a 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using Angular 9.

I am trying to construct a dynamic table from a 2 dimensional array.

I have the following which displays the first element succesffully.

```
<mat-card class="approval-edit-card-nominated">
    Nominated Evaluators
    <div>
        {{nominationAllOf[0].nominations[0].evaluatorInfo.personalInfo.name.firstName}}
        {{nominationAllOf[0].nominations[0].evaluatorInfo.personalInfo.name.lastName}}
    </div>
</mat-card>
```

However, I want to make a table that displays all rows and columns. So I try the following:

```
<mat-card class="approval-edit-card-nominated">
    Nominated Evaluators {{nominationAllOf[0].nominations.length}}
    <div>
        <table>    
            <tr *ngFor="let nomination of nominationAllOf">
                <td *ngFor="let item of nomination">
                    {{item.evaluatorInfo.personalInfo.name.firstName}}
                    {{item.evaluatorInfo.personalInfo.name.lastName}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</mat-card>
```

The `{{nominationAllOf[0].nominations.length}}` is `3`.  But the table is just not displayed.

**Question**

How do I display the table from the 2 dimensional array?

**Error**

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Thanks

Comment: `<td *ngFor="let item of nomination.nominations">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `.nominations` in your inner loop:

```
<table>    
    <tr *ngFor="let nomination of nominationAllOf">
        <td *ngFor="let item of nomination.nominations">
            {{item.evaluatorInfo.personalInfo.name.firstName}}
            {{item.evaluatorInfo.personalInfo.name.lastName}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Tip: you can easily debug such cases by using `json` pipe. In this case, you could use:

```
<tr *ngFor="let nomination of nominationAllOf">
{{ nomination | json }}
```

and you would see the contents of the `nomination` object.